# Buffer overflow OpenSSL Encryption/Decryption problems

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am currently trying to use OpenSSL to encrypt and decrypt a file, using (encrypt):

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem -in plaintext.txt -out encyrptiontext.txt
```

and for the decrypting I am using:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem -in encyrptiontext.txt
```

The keys have been generated from the same file, though when I try and decrypt a single line I receive this error:

```
8952:error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:.\crypto\rsa\rs
a_pk1.c:190:
8952:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c
:592:
```

I am not sure why I am getting this as they are using the default settings and the keys have been generated from the same generator.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site". Single CLI statements do not constitute programming. Besides that, I don't see any buffer overflow in the errors you are receiving.

Comment: It is a small part of a program that I am writing, so in that sense it is a programming problem.

Comment: Besides that this is not the best forum for the question, it will be tricky to find the underlying cause. It is very likely a problem with the keys not being correct. I do understand the error, but it can be caused by an incorrect key, incorrect ciphertext or using a padding for signing instead of encryption.